# How to get columns from 2D tensor list in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a one 2D list that contains tensors like:

```
[
 [tensor([-0.0705,  1.2019]), tensor([[0]]), tensor([-1.3865], dtype=torch.float64), tensor([-0.0744,  1.1880]), tensor([False])],
 [tensor([-0.0187,  1.3574]), tensor([[2]]), tensor([0.3373], dtype=torch.float64), tensor([-0.0221,  1.3473]), tensor([False])],
 [....] ]
```

The outer list contains 64 little list. One little list contains 5 different tensor elements.

And I want to get first elements of inner lists like `tensor([-0.0705,  1.2019])` and `tensor([-0.0187,  1.3574])` and create tensor like 64x2 to feed my neural  net.

How can I do this in the fastest way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
[item[0] for item in your_list]
```

Example:

```
li = [[tensor([-0.0705,  1.2019]), tensor([[0]]), tensor([-1.3865], dtype=torch.float64), tensor([-0.0744,  1.1880]), tensor([False])],
     [tensor([-0.0187,  1.3574]), tensor([[2]]), tensor([0.3373], dtype=torch.float64), tensor([-0.0221,  1.3473]), tensor([False])]]

[item[0] for item in li]
[tensor([-0.0705,  1.2019]), tensor([-0.0187,  1.3574])]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using slices?

```
import torch
import numpy as np
x = [
 [torch.tensor([-0.0705,  1.2019]), torch.tensor([0]), torch.tensor([-1.3865], dtype=torch.float64), torch.tensor([-0.0744,  1.1880]), torch.tensor([False])],
 [torch.tensor([-0.0187,  1.3574]), torch.tensor([2]), torch.tensor([0.3373], dtype=torch.float64), torch.tensor([-0.0221,  1.3473]), torch.tensor([False])]]
x = list(map(lambda x:list(map(lambda z:z.tolist(), x)), x))
print(x)
x = np.array(x)[:, 0]
x = list(map(lambda z:torch.tensor(z), x))
print(x)
```